# From $675n^6+2$ natural numbers find sets of $5$ consecutive naturals whose sum is cube of a natural and sum of middle three is square of a natural

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

From the first $(675n^6+2)$ natural numbers, if five consecutive natural numbers are chosen, $E$ be the event that sum of the numbers is cube of natural number and the sum of middle three is square of a natural number, then which of the following option(s) is/are true

(A) $P(E)=\frac{2}{673}$ if $n=1$

(B) $P(E)=\frac{3}{673}$ if $n=1$

(C) $P(E)=\frac{2n+1}{675n^2-2}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$

(D) $P(E)=\frac{n+1}{675n^2-2}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$

**My Attempt**

For $n=1$, I could come up with one set of five numbers viz. $673,674,675,676,677$ which satisfy the given conditions. What other possibilities can there be ?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: hint: it all comes out nicely if you introduce integer variable $x$  that will be the middle of the five consecutive integers.  The sum of the five becomes $5x$ while the sum of the middle three is $3x.$  It is then a few calculations to arrive at an explicit (polynomial) formula for $x$  that makes $5x$  an integer cubed, while $3x$  is an integer squared. Uses number theory arguments, divisibility and primes, and needs care.

Comment: Since the event $E$ is described, perhaps $P(E)$ denotes a probability assuming some probability distribution for sampling "five consecutive natural numbers".  In any case the Question is not good content for Math.SE.